# How to split a text in words, retain punctuation marks but without symbol: " ' "

Tags: python, regex

current code:

```
txt = "Jeor MORMONT, Lord COMMANDER of the NIGHT'S WATCH."
print(re.findall(r"\w+|\W+", txt))
```

output:

```
['Jeor', ' ', 'MORMONT', ', ', 'Lord', ' ', 'COMMANDER', ' ', 'of', ' ', 'the', ' ', 'NIGHT', "'", 'S', ' ', 'WATCH', '.']
```

desired output:

```
['Jeor', ' ', 'MORMONT', ', ', 'Lord', ' ', 'COMMANDER', ' ', 'of', ' ', 'the', ' ', 'NIGHT'S', ' ', 'WATCH', '.']
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to explore regex a bit more

```py
>>> print(re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z\']+", txt))
['Jeor', 'MORMONT', 'Lord', 'COMMANDER', 'of', 'the', "NIGHT'S", 'WATCH']
>>>
```

Update:

```sh
>>> import re
>>>
>>> txt = "Jeor MORMONT, Lord COMMANDER of the NIGHT'S WATCH."
>>>
>>> required = ['Jeor', ' ', 'MORMONT', ', ', 'Lord', ' ', 'COMMANDER', ' ', 'of', ' ', 'the', ' ', 'NIGHT\'S', ' ', 'WATCH', '.']
>>>
>>> bag = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z\']+|[\ ,]+|[\.]', txt)
>>>
>>> print(bag)
['Jeor', ' ', 'MORMONT', ', ', 'Lord', ' ', 'COMMANDER', ' ', 'of', ' ', 'the', ' ', "NIGHT'S", ' ', 'WATCH', '.']
>>> print(bag == required)
True
>>>
```

Comment here if I missed something.

Comment: You don't need to escape the quote :)

Comment: You too my friend, if wanted this, i woudn't put this question, look again at my question, i want spaces too, punctuation marks too, i want like this: ['Jeor', ' ', 'MORMONT', ', ', 'Lord', ' ', 'COMMANDER', ' ', 'of', ' ', 'the', ' ', 'NIGHT'S', ' ', 'WATCH', '.']

Comment: Replace the `\w+` in your original pattern with this.

Comment: Thankssss Scot Hunter, that was the problem, to replace \w+ with [a-zA-Z\']+. Thx a lot, it s pretty hard for me to understand now regex and that why i thins my question was hilarious but i m learning, thanks again

Comment: @BandRecords - can you please check updated answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
txt = "Jeor MORMONT, Lord COMMANDER of the NIGHT'S WATCH."
print(re.findall(r"[\w+|\']*|\W+", txt))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [`character set`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

You can accomplish this by using brackets `[ ]`. When using a character set, one of the characters in the set will be matched.

---

As you want either a word character or `'`, you should use:

```
[\w']+|\W+
```

- `[ ]`: A character set, matches one of the following options.

  - `\w`: A word character (the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`).
  - `'`: The symbol `'`, there is no need to escape it.

---

```
print(re.findall(r"[\w']+|\W+", txt))
# ['Jeor', ' ', 'MORMONT', ', ', 'Lord', ' ', 'COMMANDER', ' ', 'of', ' ', 'the', ' ', "NIGHT'S", ' ', 'WATCH', '.']
```